# android studio build apk error windows 10 32 bit

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, apk, legacy

I have a problem with my android studio when I **build an apk** of an opensource project **openshop.io**, something is on a **LegacyDebug task with Gradle**,I also tried removing java and android studio and installing a fresh ones **java 1.7 and 1.8** both the latest **android studio 2.2** with **android 15 API and 23 API,24 API** , also tried many of researches and solutions here but none of them works in my laptop (I have a windows 10 32 bit 4GB Ram memory), also when I try the same project on my friends laptops the **build apk**  works perfect with no changes on project but in mine not, here is the error in my android studio:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForLegacyDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

this error showes up on this task which failed to run:

Information:Gradle tasks [installLegacyDebug]